# Как узнать координаты x y по sin и cos

Tags: python

Пытался сделать стрелочные часы, но столкнулся с проблемой. Кто поможет?
Пример кода:

```
for i in range(0, 360, 60):
        pygame.draw.line(sc, (255, 255, 255), (x, y), (int(x - 100 * math.cos(i)), int(y - 100 * math.sin(i))))
```

Делал по формуле x = x0 + D * cos(a) y = y0 + D * sin(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых кто сказал, что у вас в синусы и косинусы надо передавать градусы, а не радианы ;-)

> math.cos(x) Return the cosine of x radians.

так что свой `i` из градусов в радианы переведите

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Дима, можете использовать функцию `math.radians(x)`, а не писать самопальный код через `i * 3.1415 / 180` :)

Comment: Хорошо, буду делать так